# How to add a new column based on a conditional using R?

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this:

```
Year            sales
1976 January     250
1976 February    350
1976 March       230
1976 April       255
.
.
```

This goes up-to 2003 December

I want to add a new column "Month" with a number from 1 to 12 for every year and repeating thereafter.

So that it would look like this:

```
Year            Month      sales
1976 January      1         250
1976 February     2         350
1976 March        3         230
1976 April        4         255
.
.
1976 December     12        320
1977 January      1         233
1977 February     2         333
.
.
```

Can you help me with the codes and if possible without use of any packages.

Thank you

Comment: Does the table *always* start with January?

Comment: Yes, 1976 january

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first row of the table is **always** `January`, and if no months are missing, you can do

```
table$Month = rep(1 : 12, length.out = nrow(table))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a safer way than Konrad's answer:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mydat %>%
  # Split the year from the month into a separate variable
  separate(Year, c("Year", "month"), sep = " ") %>% 
  # Add the month number based on the name of the month
  mutate(Month_num = match(month, month.name))
```

This will return the correct month number even if your rows are not properly ordered.